# I can't find simulator in atmel studio selected debugger/programmer

Tags: debugging, embedded, atmel, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

I installed atmel studio in order to find the execution time of my code on atmega 32 without connecting the microcontroller using the simulator tool, but when I start debugging it gives an error because I can't find simulator in selected debugger/programmer.

Comment: can you edit the post with the error message

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem. The Simulator option is simply not visible under Project Properties > Tools.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your code on the Atmel Studio Simulator, you need to install the Atmel Simulator extension. To do this, follow these steps:

Open Atmel Studio
Go to "Tools" -> "Extension Manager"
Search for "Atmel Simulator" in the search bar
Install the "Atmel Simulator" extension
Restart Atmel Studio
After restarting, you should now be able to select the "Simulator" as the debugger/programmer in your project properties. You should be able to debug your code on the Atmel Studio Simulator without any issues.